# SharePoint Workflow Task List

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

**Hi guys,**

I have a list (let's call it List A) which creates tasks when a new item is created into a Task list (let's call it Tasks) with the **start a task process** action in **SharePoint designer**. The purpose of Tasks is approval by management.

Creators of items in **List A** provide financial information in a few columns which management needs to either approve or reject the item.

I got some complaints from management that they have to click too many times to review the item and make a decision (they have to click on the related item in each task and go to the item which triggered the task, then go back which is causing confusion for them).

**My question is how to show this financial information in Tasks for each individual item based on the item in List A which generated the task?**

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Yordan

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to modify the e-mail that is send out to the approver and add the fields that are needed to approve the request.

You can do this in the "start a task process" action in SPD when you click on the person to whom the task is assigned. You than should be able to modify the e-mail and include the fields from any list you want.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Although, this solution can provide the necessary information in the email I will still need this in the Tasks list in order to be able to run some KPIs and metrics.

Comment: Okay, this wasn't obvious in the original question ;).

To achieve this you have to have a unique identifier in List A where the items are created. Then you can add some look-up fields in the task list and gather the additional information from List A based on the identifier.